# set Parent data value set true once child selected

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I want to set root module view to true automatically, if the child module selected, any one please help me on this and please check my JSF and Managed Bean code attached with this.

JSF code

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="assignPermission" id="assignPermissionDlgId">
    <p:panel>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:dataTable value="#{roleModule.modulesList}" var="modules"
                         id="tableId">
                <p:column headerText="Root Module ID:">
                    <h:outputText value="#{modules.moduleID}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Module ID:">
                    <h:outputText value="#{modules.rootID}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Module Description:">
                    <h:outputText value="#{modules.moduleDescription}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="View">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="view" value="#{modules.view}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Create">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="create" value="#{modules.create}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Edit">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="edit" value="#{modules.edit}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Delete">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="delete" value="#{modules.delete}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:toolbar>
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":data"
                                     action="#{roleModule.confirmMethod}" >
                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?"
                                   icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>
            <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade"
                             hideEffect="explode">
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"
                                 styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                                 styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

ManagedBean

```
    public void confirmMethod()
    {
        System.out.println(modulesList.size());

        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Connection con = getConnection();
//      System.out.println("value check"+applicationShort);
        String insert="INSERT INTO role_module_mapping VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";


        for(Module list : modulesList)
        {
            try {
                pst=con.prepareStatement(insert);
                pst.setInt(1, 0);
                pst.setInt(2, list.getModuleID());

                pst.setString(3, (list.isCreate())==true? "T" : "F");
                pst.setString(4, (list.isEdit())==true? "T" : "F");
                pst.setString(5, (list.isDelete())==true? "T" : "F");
                pst.setString(6, (list.isView())==true? "T" : "F");
                pst.executeUpdate();
//              System.out.println("Method called"+value);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:tableId')).on(
                "change",
                "input[type='checkbox'][name*='edit'], input[type='checkbox'][name*='create'], input[type='checkbox'][name*='delete']",
                function() {
                    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                    var view = tr
                            .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='view']");
                    var create = tr
                            .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='create']");
                    var edit = tr
                            .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='edit']");
                    var deleteBox = tr
                            .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='delete']");
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        view.prop("checked", true);
                    } else {
                        if (create.is(':checked') || edit.is(':checked')
                                || deleteBox.is(':checked')) {
                            view.prop("checked", true);
                        } else
                            view.prop("checked", false);
                    }
                });
        $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:tableId')).on(
                "change",
                "input[type='checkbox'][name*='view']",
                function() {
                    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                    var view = tr.find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='view']");
                    var create = tr.find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='create']");
                    var edit = tr.find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='edit']");
                    var deleteBox = tr
                            .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='delete']");
                    if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')) {
                        create.prop("checked", false);
                        edit.prop("checked", false);
                        deleteBox.prop("checked", false);
                    }
                });
    });
</script>
```

[image: Actual working scree]

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. I can't find the root module view nor the child modules. My guess is that you want to mark the checkbox (with #{modules.view}) of the row selected by the user. Is that correct?

Comment: set a id attribute for this `root module` **<p:column headerText="Root Module ID:"  id="rModule">**, then attach a change event for all the modules within in it.  `$('#rModule').children().each(function() {  $(this).on('click',function() { $(this).parent().addClass('active');   }) });` . add a css class `active` which would set some highlighting colour, just to differentiate selection of root element

Comment: In the attached screen there is two row (Root Module Id & Module ID)  root Module ID means parent module and Module ID means child ID) if user select child ID want to mark the parent checkbox (with #{modules.view}) automatically

Comment: @dreamweiver :) In my case I want check view checkbox to true

Comment: If any one have solution for my question pls post your answer. awaiting for the response. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with a tree structure using the same entity for parent and child, I would do something similar to this:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="view" value="#{modules.view}" widgetVar="ckBoxVar#{modules.rootID}" onchange="#{(modules.moduleID ne null) ? 'ckBoxVar' : ''}#{(modules.moduleID ne null) ? modules.moduleID : ''}#{(modules.moduleID ne null) ? '.check()' : ''}"  />
```

For some reason I have this strong feeling that when you write:

```
<p:column headerText="Root Module ID:">
    <h:outputText value="#{modules.moduleID}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Module ID:">
    <h:outputText value="#{modules.rootID}" />
</p:column>
```

you are actually trying to say this:

```
<p:column headerText="Root Module ID:">
    <h:outputText value="#{modules.rootID}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Module ID:">
    <h:outputText value="#{modules.moduleID}" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: You will notice that the onchange is huge. That's because I don't know a better way to concatenate strings using el expression ;).

Comment: the same solution but uncheck not working. If I uncheck i want to remove selected

Comment: Pls any one post answer for this.

Comment: You should mark every child node of a parent. One way to do that is by using css class (class="child-of-#{modules.moduleID}"). You should also consider doing a more sophisticated javascript solution for that **onchage** event.